# Asp.Net Core with legacy assembly runtime error

Tags: asp.net-core, runtime-error, .net-assembly, aforge

I have a ASP.NET Core project with TargetFramework set to net47 and class library that has TargetFramework set to net35.

Class library references AForge.Video.FFMPEG assembly. I receive the below runtime error.

> mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the
>   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information

I found that in prevoius version of .NET you could use useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy property but how to solve this in .NET Core 2.0?